# YouTube thumbnail won't load in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

We have a WebView based android app which loads webpage consisting `<a>` tags linking to YouTube video.
The web app works fine in a browsers like Chrome for Android and loads thumbnail from YouTube as expected but within WebView the `<a>` tag won't load the thumbnail of YouTube video.

How can we force the WebView to behave similar to Chrome browser

Have tried setting clients like below, which didn't help

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Even added hardware acceleration in `AndroidManifest.xml` but it didn't work either

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Note: JavaScript is also enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable javascript in your webview?

You can enable it like this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I did enable JavaScript, Sorry didn't mention on the question.